# What is the best practice in handling multiple checkboxes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

(Rails newbie) I would like to offer users multiple checkboxes "Select All That Apply".

What is the usual way one handles that data? I was thinking I could just have a column that contained a series of selected strings.

*Which foods do you like? Check all that apply*

• Pizza
• Ice Cream
• Fried Chicken
• Tacos

If a user checked Pizza and Ice Cream and submitted, I was thinking I would have a column (SurveyQuestion1) that would look like "Pizza,Ice Cream".

I don't even know where to start here.

EDIT to be more specific:

the way I actually have it set up is I have a User model, a Product model and a Survey model. The form submits to all three models with nested attributes. The User enters info about themselves, the product they bought and a few surevy-ish/preference questions at the end. The User has_many Products and Surveys. The Products belongs_to User, as does Surveys. It's been working great for me until I've become hung up on this "select all that apply" type of question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SQL database, as it seems, you should take a look at many-to-many associations. Here's a RailsGuide about that: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association.

You need to create a model for your foods. Then when a user selects his foods you store his selections on an association table that is going to have an entry for each user selected food.

Comment: the way I actually have it set up is I have a User model, a Product model and a Survey model. The form submits to all three models with nested attributes. The User enters info about themselves, the product they bought and a few surevy-ish/preference questions at the end. The User has_many Products and Surveys. The Products belongs_to User, as does Surveys. It's been working great for me until I've become hung up on this "select all that apply" type of question.

Comment: @runawayj Should the relationship between Product and User not be many-to-many (i.e. a product can be bought by more than one user), and likewise for surveys (a given survey can be completed by more than one user) ? You can then store the additional information on the join model, e.g. the user's survey answers could be in the user/survey join table.

Comment: @DaveMongoose, i suppose I don't know? The product is something specific with a unique serial number and the survey has a unique set of answers?